# What does, "Wide character array initialized from non-wide string" mean, and how do I correct it in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am trying to make a program that shows what groceries the user ordered. It will write in another file (when it's complete) the data, and show the average of each food group. It goes like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int beverage[3][20] = {
        "Soda"
        "Water"
        "Coffee"
    }; /* Here is 9 */
    int produce[3][20] = {
        "Apple"
        "Carrot"
        "Banana"
    }; /* Here is 14 */
    int dairy[3][20] = {
        "Milk"
        "Yogurt"
        "Cheese"
        }; /* Here is 19 */
    int dessert[3][20] = {
        "Ice Cream"
        "Cake"
        "Chocolate"
    }; /* Here is 24 */
    int meat[3][20] = {
        "Chicken"
        "Seafood"
        "Beef"
    }; /* Here is 29 */
    int grain[3][20] = {
        "Bread"
        "Muffin"
        "Cereal"
    }; /* Here is 34 */

    printf("Beverages: %p\n ", beverage[1]);
    printf("Produce: %p\n ", produce[2]);
    printf("Dairy: %p\n ", dairy[0]);
    printf("Candy: %p\n ", dessert[0]);
    printf("Meat: %p\n ", meat[2]);
    printf("Grain: %p\n ", grain[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

It shows the error message, "wide character array initialized from non-wide string," in lines 9, 14, 19, 24, 29, and 34. So what does the error message mean to my code? How do I change it and where?

Comment: Why are you trying to initialize ints with strings in the first place? Perhaps you meant to use `char`.

Comment: I think you probably meant to add commas between those array items, otherwise you'll end up with stuff like `Ice CreamCakeChocolate` (well, if they were `char`s instead of `int`s).

Comment: thank you @minitech I didn't notice that

Comment: Now I'm getting this:                                                     Beverages: 0x7ffff5ded774
 Produce: 0x7ffff5ded7c8
 Dairy: 0x7ffff5ded7e0
 Candy: 0x7ffff5ded6e0
 Meat: 0x7ffff5ded848
 Grain: 0x7ffff5ded874

Comment: "in lines 9, 14, 19, 24, 29, and 34" - you should probably point these out in comments in the code sample as well, SO's syntax highlighter doesn't do line numbers.

Comment: How do I correct the new problem?

Comment: @BrandonDamante, That's better suited for a new question, though there's most likely a dupe somewhere. You're printing out some kind of non-char pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If what you want are lists of strings (which I assume is what you want). You should be using `char` instead of `int`:

```
char beverage[3][20] = {
    "Soda",
    "Water",
    "Coffee"
};
```